# webrtc how to identify that a track is a screen versus a regular webcam video?

Tags: webrtc

How does one identify that a MediaStream track is a 'screen' track and not a regular webcam video track ? The MedaStreamTrack kind is 'video' for both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you get those streams from `getUserMedia()` or `getDisplayMedia()`, the best way is probably to store where you got them from in a separate map. Each track comes with an [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/id) field so you can use that as the key in your map.

If you got it over a webRTC connection, it would be best for request that information from the originating peer through a data channel.

Also kind of related is that `MediaStreamTrack.label` contains the name of the device it is displaying, which *may* contain "screen" for screen sharing, at least in Chrome. But I don't recommend relying on it since it's highly dependent on the specific browser version, host OS, and possibly the user's locale.